# Showing an ergodic toral automorphism is not measurably isomorphic to an ergodic circle rotation

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

The question as listed in the title is the question statement, only I do not want to use that one is mixing and the other is not.

Is it true that measurably isomorphic spaces are either both mixing or both non-mixing? If so, can you be so kind to tell why?

I was wondering if a direct proof to the question in the title exists that does not use mixing.

Comment: One is forward expansive, the other is almost-periodic (but this is almost philosophically equivalent to mixing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that they are not isomorphic it is fine to give a **metric** invariant that is different in the two.

For example: periodic points are very different in both cases, but the infinite set of periodic for a toral automorphism still has zero measure; I personally like mixing, but you may take entropy: one is positive and the other is zero.

PS: I wonder whether you wanted to write "hyperbolic toral automorphism" instead of "ergodic toral automorphism" since otherwise some technicalities need to be dealt with.

> **Added:** The most elementary approach seems to be showing that if $T$ is the toral automorphism and $S$ is the circle rotation, then $T\times T$ is ergodic but $S\times S$ is not ergodic, with the corresponding Lebesgue measures.

Comment: I was wondering if this problem can be tackled using only the elementary techniques in Ergodic Theory. Such as recurrence and ergodicity. Even before the ergodic theorem. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: @LandonCarter At the basic level that you describe recurrence is only **qualitative** and so there is no difference between the two (at the level of **quantitative** recurrence there are differences, but this is very much nonelementary; see for example Barreira's book). At the level that you want just show the following: if $T$ is the toral automorphism and $S$ is the circle rotation, then $T\times T$ is ergodic but $S\times S$ is not ergodic, with the corresponding Lebesgue measures.

Comment: @Jonas, working with entropy (positive entropy) implies existence of Bernoulli measure, which means "mixing apart from the Kronecker factor".